# Angular 2.0 DI can I depend upon abstractions?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-di

I've been reading the Angular 2.0 [docs](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/dependency-injection.html) about **dependency inversion** and I've been looking also at some [online examples](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular2-tour-of-heroes).

My understanding is that the `@injectable` decorator uses the TypeScript compiler with the `emitDecoratorMetadata` flag to create metadata that is used to resolve dependencies. Take for example the following class:

[image]

The TypeScript compiler uses `emitDecoratorMetadata` to declare via metadata that the `DataService` class has a constructor argument with type `Http`.

Once we have declared the dependencies of a class using `@Injectable` we can indicate that it needs to be injected into some components using the `Provides` option in the `@App` or `@Component` decorators.

[image]

I'm aware of the behaviour of `emitDecoratorMetadata` and I know that it cannot emit metadata for interfaces. Therefore, I assume that I cannot depend upon `IHttp` instead of `Http`:

[image]

Is my assumption correct? Can I depend [“Depend upon Abstractions. Do not depend upon concretions.”](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle) or is that something that is not possible at the moment? I assume this will be fixed as soon as the `emitDecoratorMetadata`becomes capable of serialising interfaces.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently you need a type, a string name or an `OpaqueToken` as key for providers.
Interfaces are not supported because the information is not available at runtime. If this gets added, I'm sure DI will support them (it's already supported in Dart).

Comment: If I use a string, how and where I map the string to the actual type?

Comment: Instead of just adding a type to providers in `bootstrap()` or components, use `provide('someName', {useClass: Http}])` and in the constructor `@Inject('someName') http:IHttp`

Answer (score 1):

If you are using TypeScript, I have a solution for you.

I am not using Angular 2.0, but we developed similiar DI library ([intakejs](https://github.com/iviru/intakejs)). The problem is TS compiler emit reflection metadata only for classes, not for interfaces (they are treated like "object").

Hopefully, they would add such functionality further, but nowdays we are using hack based on TypeScript's [declaration merging](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript-Handbook/blob/master/pages/Declaration%20Merging.md) feature. The idea is that you can declare interface, and merge it with string or some other runtime id like this:

```
export interface IMyInjectable {
    foo(): string;
}
export const IMyInjectable = 'MyInjectable';
```

Let's assume you have implementation of that interface:

```
@Injectable('MyInjectable')
class MyInjectable implements IMyInjectable {
    foo(): string { return 'hello' }
}
```

Then you can depend upon abstraction in your consumer class:

```
class MyConsumer {

    @Inject(IMyInjectable)
    private myInjectable: IMyInjectable;

}
```

I hope this little trick will solve your problem.

Comment: Looks interesting. The `Injectable` decorator doesn't support parameters like `@Injectable('MyInjectable')` though https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/758efba34bb347991991e780ed31130e642e65ab/modules/angular2/src/core/di/decorators.dart#L23. Is this necessary?

Comment: As I mentioned before, I never actually used Angular DI. But I could suppose, that `@Injectable` creates runtime id with the name of the class, so you can try merge your interface with that name.